# How to get http server response on a different device in LAN?

Tags: python, sockets, http, network-programming, python-sockets

I am new to python and my networking logics are at the beginner level. I have an HTTP server running in a VM and when I curl it from a different terminal on the same machine, I get the expected response. I am looking for a functionality where I can get the same response on my mobile device when I type the ip and port in the browser. My mobile device is connected to the same WiFi. Here's the server code:

```
import socket

MAX_PACKET = 32768

def recv_all(sock):
    r'''Receive everything from `sock`, until timeout occurs, meaning sender
    is exhausted, return result as string.'''

    # dirty hack to simplify this stuff - you should really use zero timeout,
    # deal with async socket and implement finite automata to handle incoming data

    prev_timeout = sock.gettimeout()
    try:
        sock.settimeout(0.01)

        rdata = []
        while True:
            try:
                rdata.append(sock.recv(MAX_PACKET))
            except socket.timeout:
                return ''.join(rdata)

        # unreachable
    finally:
        sock.settimeout(prev_timeout)

def normalize_line_endings(s):
    r'''Convert string containing various line endings like \n, \r or \r\n,
    to uniform \n.'''

    return ''.join((line + '\n') for line in s.splitlines())

def run():
    r'''Main loop'''

    # Create TCP socket listening on 10000 port for all connections, 
    # with connection queue of length 1
    server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, \
                                socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    server_sock.bind(('10.0.2.15',80))
    server_sock.listen(1)

    while True:
        # accept connection
        client_sock, client_addr = server_sock.accept()

        # headers and body are divided with \n\n (or \r\n\r\n - that's why we
        # normalize endings). In real application usage, you should handle 
        # all variations of line endings not to screw request body
        request = normalize_line_endings(recv_all(client_sock)) # hack again
        request_head, request_body = request.split('\n\n', 1)

        # first line is request headline, and others are headers
        request_head = request_head.splitlines()
        request_headline = request_head[0]
        # headers have their name up to first ': '. In real world uses, they
        # could duplicate, and dict drops duplicates by default, so
        # be aware of this.
        request_headers = dict(x.split(': ', 1) for x in request_head[1:])

        # headline has form of "POST /can/i/haz/requests HTTP/1.0"
        request_method, request_uri, request_proto = request_headline.split(' ', 3)

        response_body = [
            '<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1>',
            '<p>This page is in location %(request_uri)r, was requested ' % locals(),
            'using %(request_method)r, and with %(request_proto)r.</p>' % locals(),
            '<p>Request body is %(request_body)r</p>' % locals(),
            '<p>Actual set of headers received:</p>',
            '<ul>',
        ]

        for request_header_name, request_header_value in request_headers.iteritems():
            response_body.append('<li><b>%r</b> == %r</li>' % (request_header_name, \
                                                    request_header_value))

        response_body.append('</ul></body></html>')

        response_body_raw = ''.join(response_body)

        # Clearly state that connection will be closed after this response,
        # and specify length of response body
        response_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html; encoding=utf8',
            'Content-Length': len(response_body_raw),
            'Connection': 'close',
        }

        response_headers_raw = ''.join('%s: %s\n' % (k, v) for k, v in \
                                                response_headers.iteritems())

        # Reply as HTTP/1.1 server, saying "HTTP OK" (code 200).
        response_proto = 'HTTP/1.1'
        response_status = '200'
        response_status_text = 'OK' # this can be random

        # sending all this stuff
        client_sock.send('%s %s %s' % (response_proto, response_status, \
                                                        response_status_text))
        client_sock.send(response_headers_raw)
        client_sock.send('\n') # to separate headers from body
        client_sock.send(response_body_raw)

        # and closing connection, as we stated before
        client_sock.close()

run()
```

Here's the response when I run curl from a different terminal on the same VM.

[image]

I want to ping it from my mobile device connected to the same WiFi. Thank you!

Comment: it's possible that the firewall on your VM is blocking incoming requests on port 80.

Comment: You don't specify what happens if you try to use the URL in your phone so it is hard to know what your actual problem is (unable to know how to enter URL, connectivity problem, error message....). Also, line delimiter in your response should be `\r\n` not `\n`